# My windows laptop is giving error code 0xc0000221 after I dropped it

Tags: windows-10, headers, checksum, bluescreenview

It was a pretty gnarly fall, to be honest. When I start up my laptop I get a error screen that says:

```
The header checksum for this file doesn't match the computed checksum.
File: \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe
Error code: 0xc0000221
```

It also says to press F8 to enter recovery mode, but when I press F8 it reloads the same blue screen error.

Comment: What’s the question? If you have a mechanical drive it’s likely toast.  Even with an SSD any number of other components could be toast. The error is fairly common with a corrupt storage drive, the fact Windows is unable to repair itself, suggests the installation is toast.  I would take it to a computer repair shop and have them diagnose what needs to be replaced

Comment: You dropped it. You broke it. Next stop, repair shop.

Comment: Any modern drive will park heads (I have dropped a laptop wide open 4 feet onto carpet and it was fine).  So have the shop check carefully that the drop just damaged the drive.

Comment: @John that's exactly what happened to mine... except its not fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing
[Bug Check 0xC0000221: STATUS_IMAGE_CHECKSUM_MISMATCH](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xc0000221--status-image-checksum-mismatch),
defined by Microsoft as:

> This bug check results from a serious error in a driver or other
> system file. The file header checksum does not match the expected
> checksum.
>
> This can also be caused by faulty hardware in the I/O path to the file
> (a disk error, faulty RAM, or a corrupted page file).

Since you can't boot, the safest solution is to bring the computer
to a repair-shop to be thoroughly checked.
Software solutions may not work, or just hide the problem until it
bites you again.

If you can boot a Linux Live USB, you might be able to save data for which
you have no backup. If the USB doesn't boot, this means that the
computer is pretty seriously broken.